# Explaining Disjointness of Events

Tags: probability, convolution

Below is a copy and paste of Dartmouth's explanation of the sum of independent random variables:

- Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent discrete random variables with distribution functions $m_1(x)$ and $m_2(x)$. Let $Z = X + Y$. We would like to determine the distribution function $m_3(x)$ of $Z$. To do this, it is enough to determine the probability that $Z$ takes on the value $z$, where $z$ is an arbitrary integer. Suppose that $X = k$, where $k$ is some integer.Then $Z = z $ if and only if $Y = z−k$. So the event $Z=z$ is the union of the pairwise disjoint events $(X=k)$ and $(Y =z−k)$

My question is:

- Why are the events $(X = k)$ and $(Y = z-k)$ disjoint? Doesn't being
  disjoint mean that the events cannot occur simultaneously? How can these events be disjoint if what we are trying to find is EXACTLY when $k+Y = z$?

In other words, wouldn't we want to find $X=k$ and $Y=z-k$ such that their sum $k + z - k = z$ implying their intersection is not empty implying they are not disjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Why are the events $(X=k)$ and $(Y=z−k)$ disjoint? Doesn't being disjoint mean that the events cannot occur simultaneously? How can these events be disjoint if what we are trying to find is EXACTLY when $k+Y=z$?

The two events $X{=}k$ and $Y{=}z-k$ are *not* disjoint, what *are* disjoint are the *pairs* of events $\{(X{=}k, Y{=}z-k) \mid \forall k\in\Bbb N\}$

That is $(X{=}0, Y{=}z)$ is disjoint from $(X{=}1, Y{=}z-1)$, and so forth.

> In other words, wouldn't we want to find $X=k$ and $Y=z−k$ such that their sum $k+z−k=z$ implying their intersection is not empty implying they are not disjoint?

Measuring the probability of all such events is measuring that of the *Union* of the *pairs*.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}z) \; & = \; \mathsf P\Big(\bigcup_{k\in \Bbb N} \big(X{=}k, Y{=}z-k\big)\Big)\\ ~\; & = \; \sum_{k\in\Bbb N} \mathsf P\big(X{=}k, Y{=}z-k\big) & \text{since disjoint}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahhh... this makes so much sense. Basically, you cannot maintain a sum of two variables when you only change one of the variables and keep the other constant.

Comment: The union of the events, in the discrete case, would just be the summation and in the continuous case it would be the integral, correct?

Comment: @DavidSouth Yes, that is exactly *why* we seek to partition into sets of discrete atoms.